# Whatsapp calls not working on a specific Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, whatsapp-messenger, firewall

I live in Germany and I can't make a whatsapp call whenever I am connected to my home's wifi. It just goes on "connecting". Whatsapp messages work and whatsapp calls work on other wifis and my phone internet too. I checked my wifi internet speed and its around 100mbps so that is also not an issue. It seems our landlord did some firewall settings to block some websites and now she doesn't know how to enable the whatsapp calling. Or there could be some other issue. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Whatsapp requires a number or ports to be usable/free: TCP 4244, 5222, 5223, 5228, 3478, 45395, TCP/UDP 50318, TCP/UDP 59234 A second problem may arise if your provider does not provide a full IPv4 address and no working IPv6 (e.g. DSLite connection where multiple DSL users share the same IPv4 address).